# Tables created by oozie hive action cannot be found from hive client but can find them in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I'm trying to run hive script via Oozie Hive Action, I just created a hive table 'test' in my script.q , and the oozie job ran successed, I can find the table created by oozie job under hdfs path /user/hive/warehouse.  But I could not find the 'test' table via command "show tables" in Hive Client.

I think there is something wrong with my metastore config, but I just can't figure it out.
Can somebody help ?

```
oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status
```

System mode: NORMAL

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config C:\Hadoop\oozie-3.2.0-incubating\oozie-win-distro\examples\apps\hive\job.properties -run
```

Job ID : 0000001-130910094106919-oozie-hado-W

[Run Result](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9bmBLAtpkX_YkFHWnFmajB5Smc/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my oozie-site.xml

---

```
   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
```

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

```
<!--
    Refer to the oozie-default.xml file for the complete list of
    Oozie configuration properties and their default values.
-->

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.ActionService.executor.ext.classes</name>
    <value>
        org.apache.oozie.action.email.EmailActionExecutor,
        org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveActionExecutor,
        org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellActionExecutor,
        org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopActionExecutor
    </value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.SchemaService.wf.ext.schemas</name>
    <value>shell-action-0.1.xsd,email-action-0.1.xsd,hive-action-0.2.xsd,sqoop-action-0.2.xsd,ssh-action-0.1.xsd</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.system.id</name>
    <value>oozie-${user.name}</value>
    <description>
        The Oozie system ID.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.systemmode</name>
    <value>NORMAL</value>
    <description>
        System mode for  Oozie at startup.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.AuthorizationService.security.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
        Specifies whether security (user name/admin role) is enabled or not.
        If disabled any user can manage Oozie system and manage any job.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.PurgeService.older.than</name>
    <value>30</value>
    <description>
        Jobs older than this value, in days, will be purged by the PurgeService.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.PurgeService.purge.interval</name>
    <value>3600</value>
    <description>
        Interval at which the purge service will run, in seconds.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.CallableQueueService.queue.size</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>Max callable queue size</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.CallableQueueService.threads</name>
    <value>10</value>
    <description>Number of threads used for executing callables</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.CallableQueueService.callable.concurrency</name>
    <value>3</value>
    <description>
        Maximum concurrency for a given callable type.
        Each command is a callable type (submit, start, run, signal, job, jobs, suspend,resume, etc).
        Each action type is a callable type (Map-Reduce, Pig, SSH, FS, sub-workflow, etc).
        All commands that use action executors (action-start, action-end, action-kill and action-check) use
        the action type as the callable type.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.coord.normal.default.timeout
    </name>
    <value>120</value>
    <description>Default timeout for a coordinator action input check (in minutes) for normal job.
        -1 means infinite timeout</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.db.schema.name</name>
    <value>oozie</value>
    <description>
        Oozie DataBase Name
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.create.db.schema</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>
        Creates Oozie DB.

        If set to true, it creates the DB schema if it does not exist. If the DB schema exists is a NOP.
        If set to false, it does not create the DB schema. If the DB schema does not exist it fails start up.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.driver</name>
    <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
    <description>
        JDBC driver class.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.url</name>
    <value>jdbc:derby:${oozie.data.dir}/${oozie.db.schema.name}-db;create=true</value>
    <description>
        JDBC URL.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.username</name>
    <value>sa</value>
    <description>
        DB user name.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.password</name>
    <value>pwd</value>
    <description>
        DB user password.

        IMPORTANT: if password is emtpy leave a 1 space string, the service trims the value,
                   if empty Configuration assumes it is NULL.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.pool.max.active.conn</name>
    <value>10</value>
    <description>
         Max number of connections.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.kerberos.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
        Indicates if Oozie is configured to use Kerberos.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>local.realm</name>
    <value>LOCALHOST</value>
    <description>
        Kerberos Realm used by Oozie and Hadoop. Using 'local.realm' to be aligned with Hadoop configuration
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.keytab.file</name>
    <value>${user.home}/oozie.keytab</value>
    <description>
        Location of the Oozie user keytab file.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>${user.name}/localhost@${local.realm}</value>
    <description>
        Kerberos principal for Oozie service.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.jobTracker.whitelist</name>
    <value> </value>
    <description>
        Whitelisted job tracker for Oozie service.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.nameNode.whitelist</name>
    <value> </value>
    <description>
        Whitelisted job tracker for Oozie service.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.hadoop.configurations</name>
    <value>*=hadoop-conf</value>
    <description>
        Comma separated AUTHORITY=HADOOP_CONF_DIR, where AUTHORITY is the HOST:PORT of
        the Hadoop service (JobTracker, HDFS). The wildcard '*' configuration is
        used when there is no exact match for an authority. The HADOOP_CONF_DIR contains
        the relevant Hadoop *-site.xml files. If the path is relative is looked within
        the Oozie configuration directory; though the path can be absolute (i.e. to point
        to Hadoop client conf/ directories in the local filesystem.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
    <value>/user/${user.name}/share/lib</value>
    <description>
        System library path to use for workflow applications.
        This path is added to workflow application if their job properties sets
        the property 'oozie.use.system.libpath' to true.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>use.system.libpath.for.mapreduce.and.pig.jobs</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
        If set to true, submissions of MapReduce and Pig jobs will include
        automatically the system library path, thus not requiring users to
        specify where the Pig JAR files are. Instead, the ones from the system
        library path are used.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.type</name>
    <value>simple</value>
    <description>
        Defines authentication used for Oozie HTTP endpoint.
        Supported values are: simple | kerberos | #AUTHENTICATION_HANDLER_CLASSNAME#
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.token.validity</name>
    <value>36000</value>
    <description>
        Indicates how long (in seconds) an authentication token is valid before it has
        to be renewed.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.signature.secret</name>
    <value>oozie</value>
    <description>
        The signature secret for signing the authentication tokens.
        If not set a random secret is generated at startup time.
        In order to authentiation to work correctly across multiple hosts
        the secret must be the same across al the hosts.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>oozie.authentication.cookie.domain</name>
  <value></value>
  <description>
    The domain to use for the HTTP cookie that stores the authentication token.
    In order to authentiation to work correctly across multiple hosts
    the domain must be correctly set.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>
        Indicates if anonymous requests are allowed.
        This setting is meaningful only when using 'simple' authentication.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>HTTP/localhost@${local.realm}</value>
    <description>
        Indicates the Kerberos principal to be used for HTTP endpoint.
        The principal MUST start with 'HTTP/' as per Kerberos HTTP SPNEGO specification.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
    <value>${oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.keytab.file}</value>
    <description>
        Location of the keytab file with the credentials for the principal.
        Referring to the same keytab file Oozie uses for its Kerberos credentials for Hadoop.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.kerberos.name.rules</name>
    <value>DEFAULT</value>
    <description>
        The kerberos names rules is to resolve kerberos principal names, refer to Hadoop's
        KerberosName for more details.
    </description>
</property>

<!-- Proxyuser Configuration -->

<!--

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.#USER#.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
        List of hosts the '#USER#' user is allowed to perform 'doAs'
        operations.

        The '#USER#' must be replaced with the username o the user who is
        allowed to perform 'doAs' operations.

        The value can be the '*' wildcard or a list of hostnames.

        For multiple users copy this property and replace the user name
        in the property name.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.#USER#.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
        List of groups the '#USER#' user is allowed to impersonate users
        from to perform 'doAs' operations.

        The '#USER#' must be replaced with the username o the user who is
        allowed to perform 'doAs' operations.

        The value can be the '*' wildcard or a list of groups.

        For multiple users copy this property and replace the user name
        in the property name.
    </description>
</property>

-->
```

---

Here is my hive-site.xml

---

### [[hive-site.xml]](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9bmBLAtpkX_VTYtUTdRamVCY1U/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my script.q

---

### create table test(id int);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your oozie hive action you need to tell oozie where your hive metastore is.

Means you need to pass your hive-site.xml as argument.

Also you need to configure external metastore for hive for it to work. The default derby database configuration will not work for you.

So in simple steps

Create hive settings with external database , say mysql
Pass that hive-site.xml to oozie action

See here for details

http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/DG_HiveActionExtension.html

Thanks