# OOZIE workflow: HIVE table did not exists but directory created in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cloudera, oozie

I am trying to run a `HIVE` action using a `OOZIE` workflow. Below is the hive action:

`create table abc (a INT);`

I can locate the internal table in HDFS (directory `abc` getting created under `/user/hive/warehouse`) but when I trigger the command `SHOW TABLES` from `hive>`, I am not able to see the table.

This is the `workflow.xml` file:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="hive-wf">
 <start to="hiveac"/>
 <action name="hiveac">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <!-- <prepare> <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/case1/out"/> </prepare> -->
        <!-- <job-xml>hive-default.xml</job-xml>-->
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                    <value>hive-default.xml</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <script>script.q</script>
            <!-- <param>INPUT=/user/${wf:user()}/case1/sales_history_temp4</param>
            <param>OUTPUT=/user/${wf:user()}/case1/out</param> -->
        </hive>
  <ok to="end"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
 </action>
   <kill name="fail">
   <message>Pig Script failed!!!</message>
   </kill>
   <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

This is the `hive-default.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hiveuser</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>password</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.stats.autogather</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

This is the `job.properties` file:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default
oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/shared/lib
#oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/my/jobhive
```

The logs did not gave any errors as such:

```
stderr logs

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/3179985539753819871_-620577179_884768063/localhost/user/oozie/shared/lib/hive-common-0.9.0-cdh4.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/mapred/hive_job_log_mapred_201603060735_17840386.txt
OK
Time taken: 9.322 seconds
Log file: /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/taskTracker/training/jobcache/job_201603060455_0012/attempt_201603060455_0012_m_000000_0/work/hive-oozie-job_201603060455_0012.log  not present. Therefore no Hadoop jobids found
```

I came across a similar thread: [Tables created by oozie hive action cannot be found from hive client but can find them in HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709840/tables-created-by-oozie-hive-action-cannot-be-found-from-hive-client-but-can-fin)

But this did not resolved my issue. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Looks like you instructed Hive to instantiate a **"sandbox" metastore** using Derby, instead of connecting to the real metastore (MySQL?) So the CREATE TABLE was written to the Derby temporary DB... then lost.

Comment: BTW, why are you using the venerable `workflow:0.2`? What version of Oozie did you install??

Comment: I believe the `oozie.hive.defaults` is a legacy thing, forget about it -- unless you have a veeeeeeeeeery old version.

Comment: Do you have a real cluster, or just a one-node fake? If multiple nodes, do you have a valid `hive.xml` in the default YARN classpath?

Comment: I am using `Oozie client build version: 3.2.0-cdh4.1.1`. It is a very old version running on CDH 4.1.1, hene using `workflow:0.2` and `oozie.hive.defaults`. And I have a one-node cluster. Please let me know what changes need to be made for connecting with `mysql` in my `metastore`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Oozie for a couple months *(and did not keep archives because of legal reasons)* and anyway it was V4.x so it's a bit of guesswork...

1. upload your valid `hive-site.xml` to HDFS somewhere
2. tell Oozie to inject all these properties in the Launcher `Configuration` before running the Hive class, so that it inherits them all, with
   `<job-xml>/some/hdfs/path/hive-site.xml</job-xml>`
3. remove any reference to `oozie.hive.defaults`

Warning: all that assumes that your sandbox cluster has a *persistent* Metastore -- i.e. your `hive-site.xml` does not point to a Derby embedded DB that gets erased every time!

Comment: I tried changing the `oozie.hive.defaults` to the `<job-xml>` but i got the error: `Unable to connect to the metastore`, hence reverted it back to `oozie.hive.defaults`. Please suggest whats wrong in the `hive-default.xml` posted above and what changes do I need to make for pointing to the correct persistent metastore